# Java mail API - Loosing formatting in outlook

Tags: java, html, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have written a java mail api code to send an html status mail automatically to stake holders.Email body contains a table and 6 cells.I have defined table width and set the width for each cells in table.It looks like a properly formatted html when i open the source code in browser.But when i open it in outlook,table is not getting displayed as per the width set in source code.

Can someone throw some lights on finding the root cause of the issue

Below is my html message -

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<STYLE> 
TABLE.TABLESTYLE{border:inset 1.0pt;width:900;table-layout:fixed} 
TR.HEADERSTYLE{height:40pt;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;font-   size:10pt;text-align:center;background:#99DAFF} 
TR.TRSTYLE1{height:30pt} 
TR.TRSTYLE0{height:30pt} 
TD.TDSTYLE{border:outset 1.0pt} 
TD.TDSTYLE1{font-family:Verdana;font- size:10pt;background:#FFFFFF;border:outset 1.0pt;width:100pt;text-align:center} 
TD.TDSTYLE0{font-family:Verdana;font-   size:10pt;background:#F3F3F3;border:outset 1.0pt;text-     align:center;overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis} 
TD.TDSTYLE2{font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;font- weight:bold;width:200pt;background:#D1CDCD} 
TD.TDSTYLE3{font-family:Verdana;font- size:8pt;width:450pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #E9EBF0 1.0pt} 
 </STYLE> 
 </HEAD> 
<BODY> 
 <SPAN STYLE=font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;>Automation - Test Execution Details</SPAN> 
<HR><BR> 
<TABLE> 
<TBODY> 
<TR STYLE='height:12.0pt'> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE2>Executed By</TD> 
 <TD CLASS=TDSTYLE3>libinsebastian</TD> 
 </TR> 
 <TR STYLE='height:12.0pt'> 
 <TD CLASS=TDSTYLE2>Executed At</TD> 
 <TD CLASS=TDSTYLE3>DTDVD0001311PR</TD> 
</TR> 
<TR STYLE='height:12.0pt'> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE2>Total Scenarios Count</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE3>1</TD> 
</TR> 
<TR STYLE='height:12.0pt'> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE2>Total Pass Count</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE3>13</TD> 
</TR> 
<TR STYLE='height:12.0pt'> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE2>Total Fail Count</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE3>14</TD> 
</TR> 
<TR STYLE='height:12.0pt'> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE2>Test Evidence</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE3> 
<a    href=file:///S:\Data\>View Test Evidence</a> 
 </TD></TR> 
</TBODY> 
</TABLE> 
<TABLE CLASS=TABLESTYLE> 
<TBODY> 
<TR CLASS=HEADERSTYLE> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE style="width:100">SL.NO</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE style="width:200">Test Scenario</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE style="width:300">Test Case</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE style="width:100">Environment</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE style="width:100">Status</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE style="width:100">Date</TD> 
<TR CLASS=TRSTYLE0> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE0 style="width:100">1</TD> 
<TD CLASS=TDSTYLE0 title=testsitequalification - comptel     style="width:200;text-align:left">testsitequalification - comptel</TD>
```

text 
    ST1 
    Passed 
    2015-11-23 08:54:51 PM

Regards
Libin Sebastian

Comment: Without providing the code, we can only guess. Please, post the code and perhaps someone might help you.

Comment: Added source code in the question

Answer (score 1):

Mail readers often don't support the full range of html that is supported in browsers.  If the message is being displayed as html and not just plain text, and especially if you're using css, then this is likely the problem.  You may have to simplify the html you're using in your message text.  See this web site for [css support in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to set the correct mime type on MimeMessage object.

You need to use `text/html` rather than `text/plain` which is the default mime type.

```
message.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

The HTML should not contain the `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags.